# I want to replace strings from a column by names with numbers in crescent order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

I have a dataframe with a column named ID, which contains strings like: "10387-14_S91_L001" and "1590-13H-caso14_S76", a total of 20 different IDs which repeats itself along a 107 rows dataframe.

I want to replace the strings that have the substring "caso", to only "caso_00", the number that accompanies must be in crescent order; and the strings that don't contains "caso", must be replaced by "controle_00", also with the crescent order.

I tried to list only the unique() values in the column but can't continue from that

An example:

```
BEFORE                          AFTER 
0387-14_S91_L001                controle_01
10694-14_S86_L001               controle_02
590-13H-caso14_S76_L001         caso_01
1692-15G-caso20_S74_L001        caso_02
```

Comment: probably `df['ID'].str.replace('.*caso.*', 'caso00', regex = True)` to replace caso?

Comment: Can you provide head of the dataframe so I can understand your case better?

Comment: The exact expected logic would be clarified with a [mre]

Comment: I edit the question with a more clarified example, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message-working) prevents me to update my other answer. So here is an alternative.**

First create a boolean mask to determine if the row is a "controle" or "caso", then use a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) to increment your values:

```
m = df['BEFORE'].str.contains(r'caso\d+_')

df['AFTER'] = (m.replace({True: 'caso_', False: 'controle_'})
              +m.groupby(m).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
              )
```

Output:

```
                     BEFORE        AFTER
0          0387-14_S91_L001  controle_01
1         10694-14_S86_L001  controle_02
2   590-13H-caso14_S76_L001      caso_01
3  1692-15G-caso20_S74_L001      caso_02
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex:

```
df['out'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d*)(?=_[^_]*$)',
                                 lambda m: f'caso{m.group(2):02}'
                                 if m.group(1) == 'caso' else 'controle00',
                                 regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                    ID                      out
0     0387-14_S91_L001  0387-14_controle00_L001
1  1590-13H-caso14_S76      1590-13H-caso14_S76
2         123-caso_456           123-caso00_456
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vRy8Ro/1)

```
([a-zA-Z]+)  # match (and capture) letters 
(\d*)        # match (and capture) optional digits
(?=_[^_]*$)  # ensure there is a single _ and no other until the end
```

Comment: I actually wanted that the numbers that acompanies the "controle" or "caso" to be in a crescent order, as I have 20 differentes ID. So 1590-13H-caso14_S76 would be "caso00", 123-caso_456 would be "caso01", and so on

Comment: @Camila got it, see my other answer (unfortunately I couldn't edit this one)